# NetSuite - Disabling the Auto-population of Line Items on an IF

Tags: netsuite

As the title states, my company is looking for the the functionality to NOT have line item's populate on an Item Fulfillment record.

The reason for this is that we are using a 3rd party program to create shipments, and when NetSuite auto populates a line item in an IF, it causes an additional step in our fulfillment department. That step being, to delete this automatically generated line item.

Please advise & thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some additional details on how the 3rd party program is interacting with the SO/IF?

If you had a SO with a line item ABC, what happens when you click the FULFILL button? Does the 3rd party program add one more line item with its own version of ABC?
You can write a User Event script to unselect the unnecessary line item from the fulfillment record.